# If $(X,Y)$ are i.i.d. exponential then $X/(X+Y)$ follows a Beta distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I'm asked to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with parameter [image], then [image] has a Beta distribution.

Up to know I had to find the new pdf or df when $Y$ was of the kind $Y=aB + c$ which I understand now. Here a hint is given to use "Law of total probability" which I've only seen in measure theory.

My guess would be to compute [image] using the fact that the df of exponential distribution is [image]. I'm stuck at that step.

Comment: Please choose better titles.

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/412615) and (https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/the-distribution-of-xxy-is-uniform-when-x-and-y-are-iid-exponential/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naive approach:  we have $$f_X(x) = e^{-x}, \quad f_Y(y) = e^{-y}, \quad x, y > 0.$$  Define $Z = X/(X+Y)$, which implies $Y = X(1/Z - 1)$, and note that we must have $0 < Z < 1$.  Then 
$$\begin{align*} F_Z(z) &= \Pr[X/(X+Y) \le z] \\
&= \Pr[Y > X(1/z - 1)] \\
&= \int_{x=0}^\infty \Pr[Y > x(1/z - 1) \mid X = x]f_X(x) \, dx,
\end{align*}$$ by the law of total probability*.  Continuing, $$F_Z(z) = \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x(1/z-1)} e^{-x} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x/z} \, dx = \left[-ze^{-x/z}\right]_{x=0}^\infty = z,$$ hence $f_Z(z) = F_Z'(z) = 1$, and $Z$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.

---

*Note.  The law of total probability for a continuous random variable $X$ and some event of interest $A$ is $$\Pr[A] = \int_{x \in \Omega} \Pr[A \mid X = x] f_X(x) \, dx,$$ where $\Omega$ is the support of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand what you put inside your first integral. I would have simply said Fz(z) = 1 - df of Y with value x(1/z - 1). Alright, then after it won't help because we have two variables. I need to find the formula for your integral

Answer (score 0):

Define $ U = X/(X+Y) = g_u(X,Y) $ and $V =  X+Y = g_v(X,Y)$, thus 
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_X (g_u^{-1} (u,v))f_{Y} (g_v^{-1} (u,v))| \det\frac{\partial(X,Y)}{\partial(u,v)} | 
$$
where $X =UV$ and $Y = V (1-U)$, so 
$$
| \det\frac{\partial(X,Y)}{\partial(u,v)} |=v.
$$
As such, 
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v)=e^{-uv}e^{-v(1-u)}v=ve^{-v}= \mathcal{G}amma(2,1)\mathcal{B}eta(1,1).
$$
Finally,
$$
f_U(u) = \int f_{U,V}(u,v)dv = \mathcal{B}eta(1,1) = \mathcal{U}(0,1).
$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related) for more details and examples.