# Transformation and marginalization of a joint distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, change-of-variable

Suppose that the joint probability density function of X1 and X2 is given by:
$$f(x_1; x_2) = exp(−x_1 − x_2)$$ $x_1 > 0$; $x_2 > 0$ and $0$ $elsewhere$. We define Y1 and Y2 as follows: $$Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$$ and $$Y_2= \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$$

Determine the distribution of Y2.

**SOLUTION**:

I have used transformation theorem to find the distribution of Y2. Firstly I found that $X_1=Y_2Y_2$ and $X_2=Y_1-Y_2Y_1$

Jacobian determinant yields $J = Y_1$

Finally, I get:

$$f(y_1,y_2) = e^{y_1}\times y_1$$

**QUESTION**: How are the boundaries for the new joint distribution determined? I always have troubles to determine the boundaries/range in this kind of examples. Is there a technique?

To determine the marginal distribution I "integrate out" the $y_1$ (assimung the boudary is $0<y_1<1$) as follows:

$$ f(y_2) = \int_0^{1} e^{y_1}\times y_1 dy_1 = [(y_1-1)e^{y^1}]_0^1=-1$$

This doesnt seem right. I guess the boundry is where i am making the mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X,Y are independent exponentially distributed then what is the distribution of X/(X+Y)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412615/x-y-are-independent-exponentially-distributed-then-what-is-the-distribution-of-x) Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165066/if-x-y-are-i-i-d-exponential-then-x-xy-follows-a-beta-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 0):

Should be $e^{-y_1}$ and irrespective of that your evaluation of the integral can't be right as it has to be positive. Anyway, there is no $y_2$ in the density, so it must be uniform on $[0,1]$.