# How do you generate 10 values from a beta distribution?

Tags: statistics, simulation, beta-function

I want to generate 10 values from a beta distribution  on the interval [0,1] using these parameters β_1=1⋅47  and  β_2=2⋅16.Next transform them to be on the interval  [-10,20].

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You have a solution given in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/348290/147896): taking $Y_1:=U_1^{1/\alpha}$ and $Y_2:=U_2^{1/\beta}$, then $X=Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)$ follows a $B(\alpha,\beta)$ dist. But you give only $\beta$. What is the value of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: ... under the condition $Y_1+Y_2 \le 1$.

Comment: In the same spirit : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/412615/305862

Comment: Any comment ?....