# Gamma distributions and independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume that two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are [Gamma-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_.CE.B1_and_rate_.CE.B2) such that $X \sim \Gamma(a,c)$ and $Y \sim \Gamma(b,c)$ with $a, b, c > 0$.

**How can we see that two random variables $Z = \frac{X}{X+Y}$ and $W = X+Y$ are also independent?**

I am trying to see that $P(Z \leq p, W \leq q) = P(Z \leq p)P(W\leq q)$, but I can not see how to compare the both sides. Is there any other way?

(This problem is one of exercises of my textbook without any answer.)

Comment: You'll want to go jacobian route to find joint then if you can decompose this pdf to a product of functions of Z and one of W then you have independence

Comment: [How to prove these two random variables are independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261337/how-to-prove-these-two-random-variables-are-independent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(Z,W)=\varphi(X,Y)$ , where $\varphi(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{x+y},x+y\right) $ and $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, so we can use a formula for density of $\varphi(X,Y) $ : $$g(z,w)=\left| J\varphi^{-1}(z,w) \right|f(\varphi^{-1}(z,w))$$ , where $f$ is density of $(X,Y)$ and $J$ is Jacobian determinant and after some calculations we get: $$g(z,w)=\frac{1}{B(a,b)} z^{a-1}(1-z)^{b-1}I_{(0,1)}(z) \frac{c^{a+b}}{\Gamma(a+b)}w^{a+b-1}e^{-cw}I_{(0,\infty)}(w) $$ and we see that $Z$ and $W$ are independent and $Z \sim Beta(a,b)$ and $W \sim \Gamma(a+b,c)$