# Product of two densities

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, gamma-distribution

Let $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \lambda)$ and $Y \sim \Gamma(\beta, \lambda)$. I denoty by $f_X$ the density of X and by $f_Y$ the density of Y. Additionally, I assume that the density of (X, Y) is $f_X \cdot f_Y$.

Let $Z = X+Y$ and $U = \frac{X}{X+Y}$.

Why can the density of (Z, U) be written as the product of two densities?

Comment: Because U and Z are independent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190695/321264

Comment: [How to prove these two random variables are independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261337/how-to-prove-these-two-random-variables-are-independent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually Example 7c on page 284 of Sheldon Ross' *A First Course in Probability*, fifth edition.  Quoting from that source:

If $g_1(x,y) = x+y$ and $g_2(x,y) = \frac{x}{x+y}$, then

$$\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x} = 1, \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y} = 1,
\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} = \frac{y}{(x+y)^2}, \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial y} = -\frac{x}{(x+y)^2}$$ and so $$J(x,y) = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{y}{(x+y)^2} & -\frac{x}{(x+y)^2} \end{vmatrix} = -\frac{1}{x+y}$$

It turns out that $X+Y$ is distributed Gamma$(\alpha + \beta, \lambda)$ while $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is distributed Beta$(\alpha, \beta)$ and they are independent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the reference.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: So the density of X/(X+Y) is...?

Comment: It's a beta distribution, with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  The density is $cy^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}$, for $0 < y < 1$,where $c$ is a normalizing constant.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! =)