# Transformation of beta distribution into gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How can I convert a Beta Distribution to a Gamma Distribution?
Strictly speaking, I want to transform parameters of a Beta Distribution to parameters of the corresponding Gamma Distribution. I  have mean value, alpha and beta parameters of a Beta Distribution and I want to transform them to those of a Gamma Distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting" ? The Beta disrtribution is supported on $(0,1)$ whereas the Gamma distribution is supported on $(0,+\infty)$

Comment: @Ju'x the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: @Elias Sure, but what does the question mean by "corresponding"? There are infinitely many homeomorphisms between $(0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$, which lead to infinitely many possible probability distributions on $(0,+\infty)$ for each beta distribution--including every possible gamma distribution.

Comment: If I am right there is a relation between these distribution. I wanted to know how to convert parameters of beta distribution to those of gamma's.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190695/321264

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_a$ and $X_b$ denote independent gamma random variables with respective parameters $(a,c)$ and $(b,c)$, for some nonzero $c$. Then $\dfrac{X_a}{X_a+X_b}$ is a beta random variable with parameter $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a transformation as U = X + Y and V = `X/(X+Y)` where X and Y both are having gamma distribution with parameters `aplha`, `Beta` respectively. Out of these two, U will be Gamma distribution with parameters `aplha + beta` and V will be a Beta Distribution of first kind with parameter `alpha, beta`.

Answer (score -3):

if x denotes beta distribution of 1st kind with parameters @ and 1 then -logx will follow gamma distribution with parameters @ and 1