# Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ Poisson Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning, poisson-process

> Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ be two independent Poisson Process with rate
>   parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively, measuring the
>   number of customers arriving in stores 1 and 2.
>
> a)What is the probability that a customer arrives in store 1 before
>   any customers arrive in store 2?
>
> b)What is the probability that in the first your, a total of exactly
>   four customers have arrived at the two stores?
>
> c)Given that exactly four customers arrived at the two stores, what is
>   the probabity that all four went to store 1?
>
> d)Let $T$ denote the time of arrival of the first customer at store 2.
>   Then $X_T$ is the number of customers in store 1 at the time of first
>   customer arrival at store 2.Find the probability distribution of $X_T$

What I did

a)Let $T_{1i}$ and $T_{2i}$ the time of the ith customer arrives at the store 1 and 2 respectively, let $T=min(T_1,T_2)$ then we want
$$P(T_1=T)=\int_0^\infty P(T_2>t)dP(T_1=t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda_2 t}\lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 t}=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$$

b) I know that $Z_t=X_t+Y_t\sim PP(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$
$$P(Z_t=k)=\frac{e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)t}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^k}{k!}$$
then for $t=1$
$$P(Z=4)=\frac{e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^4}{4!}$$

c)Using the same idea as in a) and given that the time between arrivals is independent
$$P=(\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2})^4$$

My ideas are right? How can I make the last item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the first three answers right. For (d), we have $T\sim Exp(\lambda_2)$ so for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_T=k) &=& \int_{t=0}^\infty P(X_t(t)=k)P(T=t)\; dt \\
&=& \int_{t=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{(\lambda_1 t)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda_1 t}\right) \left(\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 t}\right)\; dt \\
&=& \dfrac{\lambda_1^k\lambda_2}{k!} \int_{t=0}^\infty t^k e^{-t(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}\; dt \\
&=& \dfrac{\lambda_1^k\lambda_2}{k!} \left[\dfrac{-e^{-t(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^{k+1}}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k \dfrac{k!}{j!} t^j(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^j\right) \right]_{t=0}^\infty \\
&=& \dfrac{\lambda_1^k\lambda_2}{k!} \left[\dfrac{k!}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^{k+1}} \right] \\
&=& \dfrac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} \left(\dfrac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} \right)^k.
\end{eqnarray*}

To see the integration result (at line $4$) you might like to use Wolfram Alpha or other automated integration - or else by repeated "integration by parts".

Answer (score 0):

For part d, here is an answer that avoids the direct calculus computation.

First, we compute what is the probability that a store 2 customer arrives before a store 1 customer arrives. Let $Z_1$, $Z_2$ be i.i.d. standard exponential. Then we are interested in

$P(\frac{1}{\lambda_1}Z_1 >\frac{1}{\lambda_2}Z_2)=P(\frac{Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2}>\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2})=\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$

where the last equality follows because $\frac{Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2} \sim Beta(1,1) \sim Unif$ (this is a well-known property of Gamma/Beta distributions; see the response by "guy" over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related)).

Now, if a store 2 customer arrives before a store 1 customer, the story ends and $X_T=0$. If a store 1 customer arrives before a store 2 customer, use the memoryless property of exponential and we reset the story after incrementing $X_T$ by 1.

Therefore, we see that $X_T$ counts the number of failures before a success, where the probability of success is $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$. Thus,

$X_T \sim Geom(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2})$