# Distribution of $\frac{X^{t}AX}{X^{t}X}$ in multivariate normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In the multivariate normal case for $X\sim N_{p}(0,I)$, consider an idempotent matrix $A$ of rank $k<p$. I need to find the distribution of $\frac{X^{t}AX}{X^{t}X}$. I know that $X^{t}AX$ follows chi square with $k$ df. The answer is that the ratio follows beta. But I'm finding it  difficulty to see how  $X^{t}X$ follows chi square with $(p-k)$ df.

Comment: With $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_p)$, you have i.i.d standard normal $X_i$'s. So certainly $X^TX=\sum_{i=1}^pX_i^2\sim\chi^2_p$.

Comment: The answer says that the ratio follows $B(k/2,(p-k)/2)$. If $X^{t}X$ follows chi square $p$, then how is  (p-k) got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$X^T X=X^T AX+X^T(I-A)X$$

By Fisher-Cochran theorem, a necessary sufficient condition for $X^T AX$ and $X^T(I-A)X$ to be independent chi-square variables is $p=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(I-A)$, which is certainly true here because $A$ is idempotent.

So $X^T AX\sim\chi^2_k$ is independent of $X^T(I-A)X\sim \chi^2_{p-k}$.

It follows from a [well-known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190695/321264) (also mentioned on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions)) that $$\frac{X^TAX}{X^T AX+X^T(I-A)X}\sim\text{Beta}\left(\frac{k}{2},\frac{p-k}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2263496/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508370/if-u-sim-chi-m2-independently-of-v-sim-chi-n2-then-prove-that-fracv?noredirect=1&lq=1.