# If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d Exponential$(\theta)$, then $X_1/\bar{X}$ is an ancillary statistic

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Here is what I have done so far: Consider the random vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ which has pdf $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n; \theta)=\theta^n e^{-\theta(x_1+\cdots+x_n)}.$$
Let $Y=T(X)$ where $T$ be the transformation that sends $(x_1,...,x_n)$ to $(nx_1/(x_1+\cdots+x_n),x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)$. The the pdf of $Y$ is 
$$\theta^n\frac{n(y_2+\cdots+y_n)}{(n-y_1)^2}\exp\left\{ \frac{n\theta(y_2+\cdots+y_n)}{n-y_1}\right\}.$$

Thus, to get the pdf of $X_1/\bar{X}$ I just need to integrate out the $y_2,...,y_n$ to show that the pdf is independent of $\theta$. And this is where I got stuck. I have tried it with $n=2$ and it worked, but integrating out this $y_2,...,y_n$, I got....lazy. :D

Do you know a better way for this problem?

Comment: Oh actually, right after I typed the question, I solved this problem. To be precise, integrating out $y_2,...,y_n$ is not that bad. But I am still interested in another approach if there is one.

Comment: $X_i$ are iid $\mathrm{Exp}(\theta) \Rightarrow$ $Z_i = \theta X_i$ are iid $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$. But $X_1/\overline X = Z_1/\overline Z$, so the distribution of this statistic is independent of $\theta$, qed

Comment: Thank you so much, zhoraster. This is a much better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@zhoraster's comment is a perfect answer to your question.

Alternatively, the exact distribution of $X_1/\overline X$ can be obtained with ease using well-known relations between Exponential, Gamma and Beta distributions. We have

$$\frac{X_1}{\overline X}=n\cdot\frac{X_1}{X_1+Y}\,\,,$$

where $Y=\sum\limits_{i=2}^n X_i$ is independent of $X_1$.

Since $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\mathsf{Exp}$ with mean $1/\theta$ (or equivalently $\Gamma(1,\theta)$), it is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655302/gamma-distribution-out-of-sum-of-exponential-random-variables) that $Y\sim \Gamma(n-1,\theta)$. Hence it is also known (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190695/321264)) that $$\frac{X_1}{X_1+Y}\sim \mathsf{Beta}(1,n-1)$$

So if you are familiar with these results, there is nothing to calculate to conclude that $X_1/\overline X$ is ancillary for $\theta$.