# Conditional density of an exponential random variable given the value of the sum.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $X_k$ be independent exponential random variables of parameter $\lambda>0$ such that

$$f_{X_k}(x)=\begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x>0\\
0 & x\leq0
\end{cases}$$

and let $S_n$ be the sum of the $n$ first $X_k$, that is,

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k=X_1+X_2+...+X_n.$$

Here, I am looking for the conditional density of $X_1/t$ given that $S_n = t$ in order to demonstrate that it is given by

$$f_{X_1/t|S_n}(z,t) =(n-1)(1-z)^{n-2},$$

a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = n-1$ where $1>z>0$.

**Here's what I did to get the wrong answer:**

First, I looked for the conditional density of $X_1$ given $S_n$ and for that, I defined a new random variable as follows

$$Z_n = \sum_{k=2}^\infty X_k = S_n - X_1$$

such that I can write

$$f_{S_n | X_1}(t|x) = f_{Z_n}(t - x)$$

knowing that the probability of $S_n = t$ given that $X_1=x$ is simply the probability of $Z_n = t - x$. I know that the density of the sum of $n$ exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ is given by

$$f_n(t) = \frac{\lambda^{n}}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}e^{-\lambda t}t^{n-1}$$

for $t>0$, I can deduce that we must have

$$f_{S_{n}}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda^{n}}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}e^{-\lambda t}t^{n-1} & t>0\\
0 & t\leq0
\end{cases}$$

and

$$f_{Z_{n}}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{\Gamma\left(n-1\right)}e^{-\lambda t}t^{n-2} & t>0\\
0 & t\leq0
\end{cases}.$$

According to Bayes formula, we get

$$f_{X_1 | S_n}(x|t) = \frac{f_{S_n | X_1}(t|x) f_{X_1}(x)}{f_{S_n}(t)}= \frac{f_{Z_{n}}\left(t-x\right)f_{X_{1}}\left(x\right)}{f_{S_{n}}\left(t\right)}$$

which then gives us the result

$$f_{X_{1}|S_{n}}\left(x|t\right)=\begin{cases}
\left(n-1\right)\frac{\left(t-x\right)^{n-2}}{t^{n-1}} & t>x>0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

From this, I can get the conditional density of $X_1/t = z$ given that $S_n = t$ since we deduce we must have

$$f_{X_1/t}(z) = f_{X_1}(zt)$$

and therefore

$$f_{X_1/t | S_n}(z, t) = f_{X_1 | S_n}(zt | t)$$

knowing that, of course, $X_1/t = z$ and $X_1 = zt$ are equivalent expressions. From what we got earlier, we get

$$f_{X_{1}/t |S_{n}}\left(z|t\right)=\begin{cases}
\left(n-1\right)\frac{\left(1-z\right)^{n-2}}{t} & 1>z>0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

which is a promising result, but still has an extra factor of $t$ in the denominator. I surely overlooked something and hopefully someone can tell me where this factor comes from and how I can get rid of it to get the answer I am looking for.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190695/321264; $X_1/S_n$ and $S_n$ are independent, so the conditional pdf is the pdf of $X_1/S_n$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ;) I did not transform my variables properly and forgot the Jacobian!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly are the beta and gamma distributions related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way: Use basu's theorem. (Use the point that @StubbornAtom mentioned.)

$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is a sufficient and complete statistic for $\lambda$.

$\frac{X_1}{S_n}=\frac{X_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} }\sim Beta(1,n-1)$ and does not depend on $\lambda$.

So By basu's theorem , $\frac{X_1}{S_n}$ and $S_n$ are independent.
["In statistics, Basu's theorem states that any boundedly complete minimal sufficient statistic is independent of any ancillary statistic."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem)

So $\frac{X_1}{S_n}|S_n \sim \frac{X_1}{S_n} \sim Beta(1,n-1)$