# Proof ratio of gamma distribution follows beta distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, transformation

If $X \sim \text{exponential}(1)$

I need to proof, using transformation method, that

$Y = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha+\beta}X_i} \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha}X_i\sim$ Gamma$(\alpha, 1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\alpha+\beta}X_i\sim$ Gamma$(\alpha+\beta, 1)$, but I can't proof that Y follows Beta using transformation method. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly are the beta and gamma distributions related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related)